# Matlab: Efficient way of inserting a row into a large matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, insert, row, memory-efficient

I am dealing with generating and modifying a quite large matrix with a size of [10^6,8]. The algorithm needs to insert a new row each time it is called in a pre-determined place of the matrix. My question is which approach would be the most memory-efficient/fastest way? Thanks.

Comment: Please add some code. where you want to add the new row in the matrix? at the beginning or end of it.

Comment: It can be anywhere, most likely somewhere within; not at the very beginning or at the end.

Comment: First of all, you should better to attach your sample code to the question to elucidate your problem. In related to the fastest way, the basic and first approach is to use [Preallocation](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/258627-about-preallocating-for-speed) . In addition to preallocation, maybe you can use other methods like vectorized calculations, but I can not say definitely without analyzing your code.

Comment: The main algorithm is sophisticated. I don't think there is any necessity to add attach it. Here, just consider a large matrix whatever you like with a new row that needs to be added into the matrix. Preallocation is not the case here for this matrix.

Comment: Sorry, there is only one way to insert a row into a matrix, and that is with `cat` (I.e. `[]`). it ain't pretty. I suggest you think of a better way to implement your algorithm. Or store your data as a cell array of row vectors if it's too slow the way you store them now.

Answer (score 1):

A basic approach to insert a row into a matrix is to split the matrix in two parts, one before the insertion offset and one after the insertion offset. Once this is done, all you have to do is to assemble a new matrix as `[part1 row part2]`.

Here is an example:

```
matrix = [
  1 1;
  2 2;
  3 3;
  4 4;
  5 5
]; 

row_to_insert = [100 100];

for insertion_offset = 0:size(matrix,1)
    disp([
      matrix(1:insertion_offset,:);
      row_to_insert;
      matrix(insertion_offset+1:end,:)
    ]);
end
```

This will output:

```
   100   100
     1     1
     2     2
     3     3
     4     4
     5     5

     1     1
   100   100
     2     2
     3     3
     4     4
     5     5

     1     1
     2     2
   100   100
     3     3
     4     4
     5     5

     1     1
     2     2
     3     3
   100   100
     4     4
     5     5

     1     1
     2     2
     3     3
     4     4
   100   100
     5     5

     1     1
     2     2
     3     3
     4     4
     5     5
   100   100
```

But if you can, consider using a different data storage approach, working with such huge matrices is always difficult, no matter how your algorithm is performing well.

Comment: Isn't it better to insert the row at the end/beginning and then change the index of the matrix to place the new row where it belongs?